# Operation of a 2 phase servo motorin flight control surfaces

Tags: current, motor, ac

So after doing some research, I briefly know a 2 phase servo motor's operation. I know it has a control and a main winding that is 90 degrees phase different to generate a rotational torque. It also has a rotor. But how does this motor move for example, flight control surfaces? Any help is appreciated thanks

[image]

Comment: Motor rotor is connected to the flight control surfaces via gears and linkages. This question may be more suited for a mechanical engineering SE

Comment: Usually via speed reduction mechanism. Gearbox connected to leadscrew for one example.

Comment: Me toy servo hobbyist a bit confused. I know toy servos are usually driven by PWM signals, and toy step motors are driven by two coils. Are you talking about 2 phase step motors?

Comment: @tlfong01 from their previous questions, I think they are talking about life size, actual aircrafts. Check out previous questions from OP. My comment is based on that assumption.

Comment: @AJN, thanks a lot for clarifying. Just now I wikied and learnt the following: "A typical two-phase AC servo-motor has a squirrel cage rotor and a field consisting of two windings: (1) a constant-voltage (AC) main winding, (2) a control-voltage (AC) winding in quadrature (i.e., 90 degrees phase shifted) with the main winding so as to produce a rotating magnetic field. Reversing phase makes the motor reverse. I only once played with single phase 12/24V AC induction motors, and that is all I know. Perhaps I can google more.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be asking about the mechanical connection between the motor shaft and, for example, flight control surfaces. There is no electrical design problem in the question.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

*How does a two phase AC servo work?*

---

***Answer***

***Part A - What is a two phase AC Servo Motor?***

---

[image: ac servo motor]

---

***Part B - How the two phase AC servo motor works***

[AC Servo Motor - Machine Design](https://www.machinedesign.com/motors-drives/article/21812597/ac-motors)

---

[image: ac servo motor]

---

*AC servomotors are used in ac servomechanisms and computers which require rapid and accurate response characteristics.*

To obtain these characteristics, servomotors have small-diameter high-resistance rotors. The small diameter provides low inertia for fast starts, stops, and reversals, while the high resistance provides a nearly linear speed-torque relationship for accurate control.

*Servomotors are wound with two phases physically at right angles or in space quadrature. A fixed or reference winding is excited from a fixed voltage source, while the control winding is excited by an adjustable or variable control voltage, usually from a ***servoamplifier***.*

The windings are usually designed with the same voltage-turns ratio, so that power inputs at maximum fixed-phase excitation and at maximum control-phase signal are in balance.

In an ideal servomotor, torque at any speed is directly proportional to control-winding voltage. In practice, however, this relationship exists only at zero speed because of the inherent inability of an induction motor to respond to voltage input changes under conditions of light load.

The inherent damping of servomotors decreases as ratings increase, and the motors have a reasonable efficiency at the sacrifice of speed-torque linearity.

Most larger motors have integral auxiliary blowers to maintain temperatures within safe operating ranges.

Servomotors are available in power ratings from less than 1 to ***750 W***, in sizes ranging from 0.5 to ***7-in***. OD.

Most designs are available with modular or ***built-in gearheads***.

---

***Part C - Locking Down Weekend EE Project Suggestion 1/2***

I once [converted a toy unipolar step motor into to bipolar](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/controlling-28byj48-bipolar-convert-with-l293d-ic).  Basically what I did was to tear down the stepper, cut something and get two disconnected coils.  Then I used DC pulse to drive the motor.

Now I have a weekend project suggestion: Instead of using DC signal, perhaps I can use low AC voltage, perhaps from a 200VAC transformer stepping down to 6VAC to drive the two winding 28BYJ-48, treating it as a two phase AC servo.

[image: 28byj48 tearing down]

***Warning**: I am just a friendly hobbyist. No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up. :)*

---

***Part D - Locking Down Weekend EE Project Suggestion 2/2***

[AliExpress 12VAC 30rpm 4W Induction motor - US$3](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/33000922268.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.40781e9ebCTgNc&algo_pvid=ff7ab61a-3bd0-4495-8e1c-01ea0da4297f&algo_expid=ff7ab61a-3bd0-4495-8e1c-01ea0da4297f-7&btsid=0ab50a5715973752456377905e8b5a&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

[Induction Motor Picture - RpiSE 2018jul](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1339514&hilit=induction%20motor%20tlfong01#p1339497)

[12V AC Induction Motor Video - tlfong01 2018jul22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tpci92yh0i8)

---

Converting 28BYJ-48 to 6VAC two phase severo motor is a bit tricky, especially if you have not used stepper motor before.  An easier project is to start with a 12V AC inductor motor.  After you have played with the cheapy US$3 AC induction motor, you might like to try you luck tearing down the motor, see if it is possible to separate the single coils into two. Yes, I tore down the motor and found it boringly simple, just a coil and no nothing.

You might like to read the above references to get to know those cheapy AC motors catalog, and how I played with one.

---

[image: ac induction motor 1/2]

---

[image: ac induction motor 2/2]

---

***References***

(1) [Servo Motor Basics - CircuitGlobe](https://circuitglobe.com/servo-motor.html)

(2) [Two Phase AC Servo Motor - CircuitGlobe](https://circuitglobe.com/two-phase-ac-servo-motor.html)

(3) [Controlling Converted 28BYJ48 Bipolar Motor - RpiSE 2019apr27](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/controlling-28byj48-bipolar-convert-with-l293d-ic)

(4) [AliExpress 12VAC 30rpm 4W Induction motor - US$3](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/33000922268.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.40781e9ebCTgNc&algo_pvid=ff7ab61a-3bd0-4495-8e1c-01ea0da4297f&algo_expid=ff7ab61a-3bd0-4495-8e1c-01ea0da4297f-7&btsid=0ab50a5715973752456377905e8b5a&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

(5) [Induction Motor Picture - RpiSE 2018jul](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1339514&hilit=induction%20motor%20tlfong01#p1339497)

(6) [12V AC Induction Motor Video - tlfong01 2018jul22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tpci92yh0i8)

(7) [Two Phase AC Servomotor - eeeguide 2014](https://www.eeeguide.com/two-phase-servomotor/)

(8) [Two-phase A-C servo motor operation - IEEE 1952oct](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6437738)

(9) [AliBaba Nema34 CNC Stepper Motor - US$70](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/CNC-controller-kit-Nema34-CNC-stepper_62081969119.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.109.2d7f7b91pPJrYE)

(10) [AliBaba 1500W AC Servo Moto Price 80b2 1500w 2.4nm 20A Driver - US$275](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-1500w-AC-Servo-Moto-Price_62532921925.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.13.2d7f7b91pPJrYE&s=p)

---

Comment: -1 Literally *nothing* to do with the question which was asked